# How to change the font in Algolia's autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, algolia

I'm using Algolia's autocomplete feature, which is working fine, but how can I change the font of the text shown in the autocomplete results? I'm using Javascript / JQuery

I would like to use a custom font (Cera) that I use in the rest of my website (which I'm loading via @font-face)

```
$('.algolia').autocomplete(
            var1,
            var2,
            var3,
            var4,
        )
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/mthuret/pen/gxEexp

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Classic autocomplete theme, you can change the font using CSS variables (or create your own style based on the Classic theme):

https://www.algolia.com/doc/ui-libraries/autocomplete/api-reference/autocomplete-theme-classic/#css-variables